# Use the same div to active two different JS function

Tags: javascript

Ive a problem: ive only one div but onclick that div must active two different JS function in two separate scripts!

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.select').live('click', function(event) {        
         jQuery('.select_dopo').toggle('show');
    });
});
</script> 

<script>
$('.select').toggle(
    function(){
        $('.lol').attr('src', 'http://oi59.tinypic.com/t8697c.jpg');
    }, function() {
        $('.lol').attr('src', 'http://oi60.tinypic.com/nzqgzr.jpg');
    }
);
 </script>
```

both use .select div for activate... what can i do for solve this problem?

this is the div

```
<div class="select"><img class="lol" src="http://oi60.tinypic.com/nzqgzr.jpg"></img></div>
```

Thx and sorry for my english!

Comment: what you're doing is setting multiple eventhandlers on a single dom-element. **that's fine** and should work, although I don't know the `toggle` handler.